Under what conditions does $AB^+B=A$ hold?
Given a matrix ${\bf A} \in \mathcal{R}^{l \times m}$ and a matrix ${\bf B} \in \mathcal{R}^{n \times m}$, under which conditions does ${\bf A}{\bf B}^+{\bf B}={\bf A}$ hold, where ${\bf B}^+ \in \mathcal{R}^{m \times n}$ denotes the Moore-Penrose inverse of the matrix ${\bf B}$?
One answer to this question is, if ${\bf B}$ has full column rank (because then ${\bf B}^+{\bf B} = {\bf I}$) but what happens if ${\bf B}$ does not have full column rank?
Or to rephrase my question:
Any matirx ${\bf C} = {\bf I} + {\bf D}$ with ${\bf A}{\bf D} = {\bf 0}$ solves ${\bf A}{\bf C}={\bf A}$. Further, let $rank({\bf B}) = r$ and ${\bf B} = {\bf U}{\bf S}{\bf V}^T$ denote the compact singular value decomposition of ${\bf B}$, such that ${\bf U} \in \mathcal{R}^{n \times r}$ and ${\bf V} \in \mathcal{R}^{m \times r}$ are (semi-)orthogonal matrices and ${\bf S} \in \mathcal{R}^{r \times r}$ is a matrix with non-zero singular values on its diagonal, then
$${\bf B}^+{\bf B} = {\bf U}{\bf S}^{-1}{\bf V}^T{\bf V}{\bf S}{\bf U}^T = {\bf U}{\bf U}^T$$
When is ${\bf U}{\bf U}^T = {\bf I} + {\bf D}$?

Given $I - B^+B$ is the orthogonal projector onto the nullspace of $B$, $AB^+B = A$ if and only if $A(I - B^+B) = 0$, i.e. the nullspace of $A$ contains the columnspace of $I - B^+B$, i.e. $\operatorname{null} B \subseteq \operatorname{null} A$.

The condition is that each row of $\mathbf{A}$ lies in the row space of $\mathbf{B}$, i.e.,
$\exists\ \mathbf{L} \text{ s.t. } \mathbf{A}=\mathbf{LB}. $
$$\begin{align}
&\  \mathbf{A}=\mathbf{LB}\\
\Longrightarrow &\ 
  \mathbf{A}^T=\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{L}^T\\
\Longrightarrow &\ 
  \left(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{B}^T\left[\mathbf{B}^T\right]^+ \right) \mathbf{A}^T = \left(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{B}^T\left[\mathbf{B}^T\right]^+ \right) \mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{L}^T \\
\Longrightarrow &\ 
  \left(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{B}^T\left[\mathbf{B}^+\right]^T \right)\mathbf{A}^T = \left(\mathbf{B}^T - \mathbf{B}^T\left[\mathbf{B}^T\right]^+\mathbf{B}^T \right) \mathbf{L}^T \\
\Longrightarrow &\ 
  \left(\mathbf{I} - \left[\mathbf{B}^+\mathbf{B}\right]^T \right)\mathbf{A}^T = \left(\mathbf{B}^T - \mathbf{B}^T\right) \mathbf{L}^T =\mathbf{0}_{m\times\ell} \\
\Longrightarrow &\ 
  \mathbf{A}^T =  \left[\mathbf{B}^+\mathbf{B}\right]^T \mathbf{A}^T \\
\Longrightarrow &\ 
  \mathbf{A} =  \mathbf{A} \mathbf{B}^+\mathbf{B}\\
\end{align}
$$
